# Cast Scientific number to Decimal in Hive

Tags: sql, hive

I want to cast the number which has scientific notation to Decimal in Hive, But I am getting wrong output. Where I am doing wrong..

Below is my query to test.

```
select cast(-1.36666E2 as decimal(6,1))
```

I am expecting the output to be **-1.36666** . But I got **-136.7**

Comment: The output is correct. If you expect -1.36666 then trim E2

Comment: May be my precision is wrong. Is there any way without trimming?

Comment: Which one is wrong ? The value of -1.36666E2 is -136.66

Comment: I edited my question..  Which Precision I need to use to get -1.366666 ?

Comment: you should cast as `decimal(12,6)`?

Comment: @SebastianBrosch Not working.. Got -136.66..  How this precision thing works..  ? The first value is no. of digits and 2nd value is where decimal point starts.. right ?

Comment: yes - it was only a idea ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DECIMAL(precision, scale) is the data type.

Precision is the number of digits in a number. 
Scale is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point in a number.

For example, the number 136.7 has a precision of 4 and a scale of 1
So if you have 1.36666 , precision is 6 and a scale of 5

```
select cast(-1.36666E2 as decimal(6,3))
```

-1.36666E2 is -1.36666* 10^2. That will return -136.666. You will not get -1.36666 for the input -1.36666E2