# hive- how do I convert scientific notation to decimal value

Tags: hive

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46763354/cast-scientific-number-to-decimal-in-hive) accepted answer, I should change 1.2766E-10 to decimal like below:

```
select cast(1.2766E-10 as decimal(11, 10))
```

but it gives me, 1E-10. How can I disable scientific notation in Hive or how can I convert such small numbers in scientific notation to decimal values?

Comment: Did you solve this @Fisseha Berhane

Answer (score 0):

1.2766E-10  is -6.52984141779, so there are 12 numbers for precision and 11 numbers for scale.

```
select cast(1.2766E-10 as decimal(12, 11))
```

[image]

Comment: that gives me 1.3E-10

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing scientific notation with Euler number.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

**cast(format_number(1.2766E-10,10) as STRING) as col**

```
+------------+
|col         |
+------------+
|0.0000000001|
+------------+
```

OR

**cast(format_number(1.2766E-10,14) as STRING) as col**

```
+----------------+
|col             |
+----------------+
|0.00000000012766|
+----------------+
```

I hope this will be helpful.